# Como puedo insertar productos en Woocommerce vía PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

Buenos días comunidad StackOverflow, estoy buscando por la red y no doy los códigos que debo de trabajar para poder realizar una inserción en la base de datos de un producto woocommerce.

Me preguntaba a ver si alguien de ustedes, sabe como insertar productos al woocommerce vía PHP, **¿Cuales son las Queries que debo utilizar para introducir productos por PHP?**, *Insertando el nombre del producto, la imagen y los precios correspondientes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de querys, puedes usar la propia API de wordpress y woocomerce desde php de forma muy sencilla, en tu módulo, el código para importar sería:

```
<?php
    require 'wp-load.php';
    $post = array(
        'post_title'   => "Nombre del producto",
        'post_content' => "Contenido de la descripción",
        'post_status'  => "publish",
        'post_excerpt' => "excerpt",
        'post_name'    => "nombre",
        'post_type'    => "product"
    );
    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_weight', "0.06");
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_sku', "codigo");
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_stock', "100");
    update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_visibility', 'visible');

    $id_familia = 80;
    wp_set_object_terms($new_post_id, $id_familia, 'product_cat');

    $my_product_attributes = array(
        'color' => "rojo",
        'forma' => "circular"
    );
    wcproduct_set_attributes($new_post_id, $my_product_attributes);
?>
```

También puedes cambiar otros campos:

```
//update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_regular_price', '');
//update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_sale_price', '');
```

El $id_familia = 80; sería la familia del producto.

Añadido posterior:

Falta la función para los atributos:

```
function wcproduct_set_attributes($post_id, $attributes) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
        $product_attributes[$i] = array (
            'name' => htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($name)), // set attribute name
            'value' => $value, // set attribute value
            'position' => 1,
            'is_visible' => 1,
            'is_variation' => 1,
            'is_taxonomy' => 0
        );
        $i++;
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
}
```

Comment: Pero antes debería de realizar un require_once() algún archivo php, para que cargue la clase wp_insert_post??. La idea que una vez introduzca los datos a phpmyadmin, lo ejecute con la tarea CRON, cada cierto tiempo. Te digo esto, porque no se si debería de crear un modulo en php, para realizar simplemente unas comprobaciones e insertar DB.

Comment: Si, así es, primero hay que llamar a wordpress así: require './admin/wp-load.php'; otra opción es hacer un módulo, claro.

Comment: Gracias track3r, funciona ya que se inserta en la base de datos pero, me devuelve el siguiente error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wcproduct_set_attributes()`
Supongo que se deberá de cargar algún archivo mas, para insertar los atributos

Comment: Cierto, te falta una función, la añado a la respuesta.